# How to execute consecutive commands from history?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history

Suppose I want to execute a sequence of four commands that I have executed before. If the first one is 432 in the command-history, then I could do:

```
$ !432; !433; !434; !435
```

I'm curious, is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because it doesn't *execute* the commands, but you could type `history -p \!43{2..5}` to print commands 432 through 435 to the terminal, suitable for subsequent copy/paste.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If it refers to commands run just recently, a more efficient way is to reference them with negative numbers:

```
!-4; !-3; !-2; !-1
```

Also, once you do it, your last history entry will contain the whole chain of commands, so you can repeat it with `!!`.

---

**Edit:**
If you haven't already, get familiar with the great builtin function **`fc`, [mentioned by Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24763/9382)**. (Use `help fc`.) It turns out that you can also use negative numbers with it, so you could do the same as above using

```
eval "`fc -ln -4 -1`"
```

This has one caveat, though: after this, the `eval` line is stored in the history as the last command. So if you run this again, you'll fall into a loop!

A safer way of doing this is to use the default `fc` operation mode: forwarding the selected range of commands to an editor and running them once you exit from it. Try:

```
 fc -4 -1
```

You can even reverse the order of the range of commands: `fc -1 -4`

Comment: I just read what I'd written... LOL. Actually, I'm not sure about *reinvoke* (*re-invoke* maybe?), but thanks for telling :) I always appreciate corrections.

Comment: Scrabblefinder.com says reinvoke is a valid Scrabble word. Can't get any more definitive than that. :)

Comment: With a good answer like this one (+1), it doesn't matter how you spell it; especially as neither spelling form shows up in 3 *major* English dictionaries: Oxford, Camgridge, Merriam-Webster (I'd go for the hyphen)

Answer (score 41):

To view a range of commands in the history use the built-in [`fc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html#Bash-History-Builtins) command:

```
fc -ln 432 435
```

To execute them again:

```
eval "$(fc -ln 432 435)"
```

Comment: Very nice. I'm curious though, why `man fc` doesn't give me anything. What does `fc` stand for? What other options are there?

Comment: *@Eric Wilson* ... type `help fc`... and also `help help` .... *help: help [-dms] [pattern ...]
    Display information about builtin commands.*

Comment: I just came back here, searching for your answer. This really is a great builtin! Especially when you is its default functionality - invoking an editor to modify a range of commands to be replayed. Thanks, Gilles.

Comment: Without `-l` flag, it will execute without need for the evil `eval`.

Comment: @Bernhard There's nothing evil about eval. This isn't javascript. Understand the tool and don't arbitrarily toss shade because it's de rigueur.

Comment: @EricWilson A google search lead me to the "Unix in a Nutshell" [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=_TdsEAvH9OUC&pg=PT389#v=onepage&q&f=false) which says `fc` stands for "find command" or "fix command".

Answer (score 15):

There is a nice and alternate way to run a number of commands in sequence from the Bash history:
instead of using history substitute (`!432` or `!-4`), you can search through the history with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, and once you've found the first command you want to run, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (*operate-and-get-next*) instead of the <kbd>return</kbd> key
This will *launch the command and propose the next one* from the history.
You can hit <kbd>Ctrl+o</kbd> as many time as you wish, and end the sequence either with <kbd>return</kbd> for a last one, or <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> to stop without launching it.

Comment: Hmm, after I hit `Ctrl-o` it just outputs a literal `^o` and breaks my `(reverse-i-search)`. Maybe there is some other setting involved.

Comment: thank you very much! couldn't recall the combination and had hard time finding it, although the combination is quite simple

Answer (score 14):

To execute the commands immediately rather than edit them, here is a syntactically slimmer version of [Giles answer using eval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24763/9382):

```
fc -e: 432 435
```

The colon argument to -e is the bash noop, which has the effect of skipping the "open in an editor" step that fc wants.  Also, now the (recent) history will contain the actual commands from history, rather than the eval statement.

Comment: this is the most practical answer

Answer (score 0):

**`fc` for loop and `xsel`**

This works well when I want to concatenate and re-run the last n commands multiple times:

```
fcn() (
  from="${1:-2}"
  to="${2:-1}"
  if [ "$from" -ne "$to" ]; then
    for i in `seq "$from" -1 "$(($to + 1))"`; do
      printf "$(fc -ln -${i} -${i}) && "
    done
  fi
  printf "$(fc -ln -${to} -${to})"
)
```

Then:

```
$ echo a
a
$ echo b
b
$ echo c
c
$ fcn 3 1 | xsel -b
$ # Paste.
$  echo a &&  echo b &&  echo c
a
b
c
$ # Paste again if you feel like it.
$  echo a &&  echo b &&  echo c
a
b
c
```

Or for larger commands that might need some editing:

```
fcn 3 1 >cmds.sh
vi cmds.sh
bash cmds.sh
bash cmds.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

```
fcn 3 1 >cmds.sh
vi cmds.sh
bash cmds.sh
bash c
```

Comment: I'm not sure that redirection, editing, executing a script, and then potentially removing the temporary file is a "more efficient way to accomplish this".

Comment: Also, what's the intention behind `bash c`?