# Re-run multiple history commands

Tags: bash, command-history

Imagine you've just run a dozen commands. Say...

```
$ cd foo/    # history cmd #10000 (my history is very long)
$ ... more commands ...
$ cd ../     # history cmd #10012
```

I know I can re-run them concatenated with `!-12 && !-11 && !-10 && (and so on) && !!` if they happen to have *just* been run (unlikely) or `!10000 && !10001 && !10002 && (and so on)`, but is there a simpler way than hand-typing each history number with a bang and ampersands?

Is there perhaps some kind of range thing I'm unaware of in bash?

e.g. `!{10000-10012}` # something like this, only working.

Comment: Best solution I saw was this one from fear_no_eval: fc -e: 10000 10012 (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428639/77894)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is what the [`fc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fc.html) command is for.  For the last 12 commands:

```
fc -12 -1
```

or for commands numbered #10000 to #10012

```
fc 10000 10012
```

This is not quite what you want as it will launch an editor first, but that is probably a good thing since it gives you a chance to double check that you have the correct commands and even edit them using all the capabilities of your favorite editor.  Once you save you changes and exit the editor, the commands will be run one after another.

Comment: Ah hah! Brilliant! `fc`. Fix Commands. Makes sense!

Comment: To avoid launching an editor (dangerous!), you can use `fc -e true -12 -1`

Comment: unavailable in ubuntu

Comment: @okwap, nonsense.  It's [POSIX specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fc.html) and certainly available in Ubuntu.  (It's a shell built-in, though—as it *must* be—so if you're looking in `/bin` you won't find it.)

Comment: Is the only way, if you decide once you're in the editor that you wish to abort, to delete the contents? (if I type `:q!`, Vim quits but the commands execute anyway).  Here's the [man page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1p-fc/) if it helps anyone else.

Comment: @WilliamTurrell You can try quitting the editor with a nonzero exit code, I'm told `:cq` will do this in Vim.